# Splitting a directory of 14 million files to multiple subdirectories

Tags: bash

I have a directory called `direct` and it contains 14 million files that have the form file54.txt , where the number 54 in name file54.txt could be replaced by any natural number between 1 and 14 million. Is there a way to split those files into for example 1000 sub-directories in the directory titled `direct` that contain in total all of the 14 million files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
for (( i=0; i < 14000000; ++i )); do
    (( dirname=i/14000 ))
    if (( i%14000 == 0 )); then
        mkdir -p direct/$dirname
    fi
    mv direct/file$i.txt direct/$dirname/file$i.txt
done
```

Comment: Of course with mv it's gonna take several hours for 14 million files. However if you use a language other than shell script e.g. python, java or c, it should go much faster. I know from experience that with java it takes about half an hour on a linux system with a single 2 TB hard disk.